# Want to know which relationship should be applied between pets object and donar object

Tags: lookup, relationships, object

Question
*List of pets (waiting for adoption and adopted)
*Track people who adopted a pet
*Receive money donations (track donors and total of donations by donor)

I created a pets object which has a lookup to its owner(object),
but lookup between pets(object) and donar(object) should not be applied because it is not necessary that ever pet is donated by any donar, so which relationship i should use in between pets And Donar object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a lookup relationship.
One person can adopt several pets.
A pet can be adopted by only one person.
If pet has not been adopter, lookup is empty.

Another thing to consider is visibility. If you have access to see a person, you will not necesary have access to see pets adopted by the person.

If you delete a person, you will not necesary have to delete a pet.

Answer (score 0):

We have two types of relationship in Salesforce.

- Lookup
- Master Detail

As they are not required so you should go with Lookup Relationship.

But according to your use case you can create a Junction Object which will allow you to give Many to Many relationship because one donar might donate many pet.

You can check About Relationship in More detail here:

- [Relationships Among Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm)

Comment: I thought of making junction Object but one pet will never have more than one donar.

Comment: @Ana one Donar might have multiple pet, Possible? if no then normal lookup will work otherwise junction will be good.

Comment: Okay, i m going to try it once again and thank you.